# Is there a way to use Jinja2 to filter JSON data from a HTTP POST request?

Tags: json, jinja2

I am using Home Assistant, which templates data via Jinja2.

Is it possible to use a Jinja2 template to remove the HTTP POST header and keep the JSON data only?

The data I am using is:

```
POST /api/V1/sensor/UploadSensor HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: al.lewei50.com
Connection:close
Content-Length: 448

{"method":"uploadsn","version":"ABC","type":"AL_TH","SN":"ABC","Data":[13.8,8.4,352.8,364.4,10.0,257.7,7616,50,25.700,29030.140,null,4868,3060,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,2575,2540,2501,10.0,9.9,253.6,251.4,50.03,50.04,50.04],"Information":["null","000.01","ABC  ","ABC"],"Status":"4883"}
```

and I need to have a template to show only:

```
{"method":"uploadsn","version":"ABC","type":"AL_TH","SN":"ABC","Data":[13.8,8.4,352.8,364.4,10.0,257.7,7616,50,25.700,29030.140,null,4868,3060,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,2575,2540,2501,10.0,9.9,253.6,251.4,50.03,50.04,50.04],"Information":["null","000.01","ABC  ","ABC"],"Status":"4883"}
```

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP response consists of the header, a blank line, and then the response body. Since you want only the response body, your solution is:

- Split your data on the empty line, and then
- Take the second element of the resulting list.

Assuming your data is in a variable named `response`, you want something like:

```
{{ response.split('\n\n')[1] }}
```